# electron: drag range control while holding meta key

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

With Electron, I'm wondering how to capture meta-key event when dragging the thumb of a range control, or increment/decrement the number control, a shift-drag or option-drag on the slider, shift-click or option-click on number's spins.

There is the `globalShortcut` API, but it is a broader API for even when the window is out of focus. **And worse, it does not register a single meta key event. The supported events must be `meta+regular_key`**. I need to detect events on a single meta-key.

More importantly, using the API, it basically requires global variables as states to be shared with whatever parts of the code that require those states, which is ugly.

Is there a way such as with other widget library where meta-keys are part of the API signature?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this global variable solution for now.
Not sure if this is the best way.

```js
var gShiftKeyHeld = false;
// CAUTION:
// - keypress not fired in Chrome for meta keys.
document.addEventListener('keydown', (evt) => {
    gShiftKeyHeld = evt.shiftKey;
});
document.addEventListener('keyup', (evt) => {
    gShiftKeyHeld = evt.shiftKey;
});
```